# Green Screen Streaming

Tags: video, software-recommendation, greenscreen

I am a complete newbie when it comes to making videos. Just got a Canon VIXIA RF62, and built a DIY green screen. On the green screen I hope to place maps and other background images that I will point to in my presentation. I know I can add these things in post-production, but I want to be able to look at myself in a monitor, with the images in place, so I can see where to point in real time.

I was thinking of hooking my camcorder into my PC laptop via the HDMI out cable on the camcorder. The idea being that I could hook up a monitor next to the camera that I could see while filming, so I can tell where to point. I don't want to just look at me in front of a green screen.  At the same time I want to be recording the whole thing.

I have not as of yet bought any video editing software. Is there some that can do decent amateur video editing, and still do what I want it to from a streaming perspective? Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways of achieving this.

1. Use a hardware solution. They are available from Datavideo or on most video switchers. Obviously, these cost money and the results are dependant on how well you've lit your setup.
2. For a software solution you will, like you've mentioned, need to connect your camera's video output to your computer. (It seems you have an HDMI output) Therefor you will need an HDMI input on your laptop. If your laptop supports USB3 or Thunderbolt you can look at solutions from Blackmagic Design (among others) to capture the HDMI feed over USB3 or Thunderbolt. The Thunderbolt solution is really affordable, the USB3 solution, less so.
3. Some of the BMD models allow you to do Live-Chromakeying in the Blackmagic software.
4. For Windows I came across this software, http://vidstudio.com/ it seems free and allows for live-chromakeying.
5. For the Apple filmmakers among us. A quick search on Live-Chroma Keying OSx will result in a large selection of affordable software.

Especially when you are going to do the actual keying in the post process, you don't need the highest quality live killer. These are often times very expensive and give moderate results at best.